# How does one monitor the progress of a RIA WCF submit call?

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I have a RIA SubmitChanges call off my domain context:

```
_context.SubmitChanges((results) => ...do something for errors on return
```

Is there anyway to monitor the progress of SubmitChanges while it is transferring the entity set over RIA ?  I use a BackgroundWorker thread to do my processing (not the RIA calls, as they seem to spawn their own thread), and it has a ProgressChanged event that fires when work in the worker thread is done.  I capture it for recording the percentage of my entities buffered in memory, but I'd like to have an event fire on every successfull WCF RIA commit....sort of a "percentage saved to server".

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could monitor multiple requests, I suppose. But as far as a single SubmitChanges() call there isn't going to be a progress response from the server as this is sent as one change set, not a series of individual requests.